# How to print something from another class

Tags: java

I was wondering how to print something from another class. I'm sure its on here somewhere I just don't know where.

```
 public class AddNumbers{
  public static void main(String[] args){

    System.out.println(c);//want to print from add class add here
}
public static void Add(int[] args){
    int a = args[0];
    int b = args[1];
    int c = a+b;
}
}
```

Comment: `Add` is not a class, it's a method, and you may call it from your `main()` method by just passing it an array of integers.

Comment: If you want to print `c` in `main` then you could change your `Add` method to return the value of `c`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways:
1. Print out directly from function `Add`

```
public static void Add(int[] args){
    int a = args[0];
    int b = args[1];
    int c = a+b;
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

2. Change function to return a value.

New class:

```
public class AddNumbers{
   public static void main(String[] args){
       int something = Add(args);    
        System.out.println(something);
  }
    public static int Add(String[] args){
      int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
      int b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
      int c = a+b;
      return c;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As other posters have pointed out, what you have is a static method. Static variables are known as **class members**, and there's just one copy of it shared amongst all instances of the class. This is different from instance variables in which all objects have their own copy.

**Here's some code to help explain class members.**

```
public class FrozenApples {

    private static int apples;

    public void setApples(int quantity) {
        apples = quantity;
    }

    public int getApples() {
        return apples;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        FrozenApples one = new FrozenApples();
        one.setApples(100);
        FrozenApples two = new FrozenApples();
        two.setApples(200);

        System.out.println(one.getApples()); // 200
        System.out.println(two.getApples()); // 200
    }

}
```

Now back to your code. One solution to retrieving c is to return it which requires modifying the method’s signature as htpvl has demonstrated. Since int a and int b are created inside a method and not returned, they're not accessible outside of the method. For further reading check out [Variables from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html). 
If you're short on time read this section from the above.

> Local Variables Similar to how an object stores its state in fields, a method will often store its temporary state in local variables. The syntax for declaring a local variable is similar to declaring a field (for example, int count = 0;). There is no special keyword designating a variable as local; that determination comes entirely from the location in which the variable is declared — which is between the opening and closing braces of a method. As such, local variables are only visible to the methods in which they are declared; they are not accessible from the rest of the class.

Answer (score -1):

If the method add is in a different class, you can add a method that returns c. Then, you can call it from outside the class wherever you instantiate an object from that class.   You can then do System.out.println(yourobject.get(c);

```
public static void Add(int[] args){
    int a = args[0];
    int b = args[1];
    int c = a+b;
}
public int getC(){
return c
}
```

If the method is in the same class as your main method, you can simply modify it to return c, as shown above.